# Slow connection times to FileMaker via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc, filemaker

I know this is an open-ended quesiton, but I was hoping someone might have some tips to improve FileMaker ODBC performance...

**Situation:** VB.NET application talks to FileMaker Pro Server 11 running on Windows 2008 Server.

Code:

```
Dim cn2 As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("DRIVER={FileMaker ODBC};SERVER=192.168.1.5;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;DATABASE=xxx;") 

cn2.Open() 'takes 0.37 seconds (way too slow)?!
```

For comparison, opening a connection to a MSSQL Server on a different machine takes 0.01 seconds the first time, and 0 seconds any time after that.

Any thoughts? Is this normal for FileMaker?

Comment: check if is there any field called uid in your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For FileMaker ODBC, it's best to use a separate database file for ODBC for access - it can still reference external tables, etc. but keep only the tables you need in the file. This should greatly improve performance.

Comment: I have tested this further using a standalone Filemaker DB not having references to anything, and it was quick to connect. The Filemaker DB I was having problems with has quite a few references to other Filemaker DB's on the same server - perhaps the cause of the slow connection time.